# Too many UnknownProducerIdException in kafka broker for kafka internal topics created for kafka streams application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

One of Kafka stream application is generating a lot of Unknown Producer Id errors in the Kafka brokers as well as on the consumer side.

Stream Configs are as below:

```
final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appName);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG,appName + "-Client");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.bootstrapServer);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG,StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offset);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG,state_dir);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG,defaultReplication);
    return streamsConfiguration;
```

Error on the broker side:
[image]

Error on the consumer side:

[image]

custom configuration for repartition internal topic:
**prod.Prod-Job-Summary-v0.4-KTABLE-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000049-repartition**
[image]

What can be the reason behind these?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue. See [KAFKA-7190
Under low traffic conditions purging repartition topics cause WARN statements about UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7190) and [KIP-360: Improve handling of unknown producer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-360%3A+Improve+handling+of+unknown+producer).